# Find files whose path doesn't contain a word

Tags: linux, path, find

I am trying to list all the `.hpp` files but those whose path contain a word, 
for example :

`find -name '*.hpp'` would give

```
folder1/folder2/something.hpp
folder1/folder3/something.hpp
folder1/folder4/something.hpp
```

I'd like to exclude the files in the folder2 in order to have only these :

```
folder1/folder3/something.hpp
folder1/folder4/something.hpp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just negate a `-path` condition:

```
find -name '*.hpp' -not -path '*/folder2/*'
```

To exclude several directories, either repeat the condition:

```
find -name '*.hpp' -not -path '*/folder2/*' -not -path '*/folder3/*'
```

Or use alternative in a regex:

```
find -name '*.hpp' -not -regex '.*/\(folder2\|folder3\)/.*'
```

Comment: Thank you, and how can I exclude an other folder ?

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun: Dot in a regex means "any character". `*` means "repeated zero or more times".

Comment: yeah, that means that they are not important here, no ? I would get what I need without them

Comment: I mean `'.*'` is included in `'*'` so the results `'.*/\(folder2\|folder3\)/.*'` should be included in `'*/\(folder2\|folder3\)/*'`

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun: No, `-name` uses "patterns", not regexes. `*` in patterns translates to `.*` in regexes.