# How find files with 'gtk' that aren't 'permission denied'

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I'm trying to find files in linux with *gtk* in the name, but I'm getting a lot of garbage **permission denied** in my output.  I'm trying to figure out how to trim the results, and was reading [trim it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19430/how-do-i-remove-permission-denied-printout-statements-from-the-find-program/121020#121020) and [find it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026599/find-files-whose-path-doesnt-contain-a-word), but I'm having trouble putting the info from those posts together with finding the file and path to the file.

This is how I find the file, with permission denied in output:

```
find . -ipath '*gtk*' | grep gtk
```

I tried cleaning up permission denied, but it's not working (shows no files):

```
find / \! -readable -prune -o -name . -ipath '*gtk*' -ls | grep gtk
```

I tried this too, but it still shows permission denied in output:

```
find . -ipath '*gtk*' -not -regex 'Permission' | grep gtk
```

Tried this too:

```
find . -ipath '*gtk*' ! -readable ! -executable -prune -o -print | grep gtk (error with -o)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe stderr to a file so you don't have to see it:

find . -ipath '*gtk*' | grep gtk 2>error.log